# New GCM google-services.json and plugin needed?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

The latest GCM update includes steps on developer.google.com to create a configuration file and use a gradle plugin.  I have an existing app that already configured to use GCM.  Is switching to the plugin recommended?  Will this cause any problems.  Looks like Google is moving to using this plugin & google-services.json as the configuration for all Google apis.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the plugin will not cause any issue with your current projects. The google-services plugin assists in the creation and use of projects from the Google Developer Console in your Android application. It provides constants that map to values from your console projects eg: gcm_defaultSenderId for GCM. The values could still enter manually, so you have the option of not using the plugin.

Comment: I'm always a bit cautious with tools that hide things.  Any idea if the site that creates this config file generates new api keys or uses existing data in the developer console for my app?

Comment: It should only create new credentials if your current set of credentials are insufficient.